# display selected checkbox options on the page

Tags: javascript

was wondering if i could get a little help. I have 3 checkboxes and want to display the text before each checkbox back to the user.

```
<form id="extras" onchange="calculate()">
    option 1<input type="checkbox" name="box" value="2000" id="snow" onchange="calculate()" checked><br>
    option 2<input type="checkbox" name="box" value="500" id="water" onchange="calculate()" checked><br>
    option 3<input type="checkbox" name="box" value="150" id="air" onchange="calculate()"><br><br>
</form>
```

so i can say you have selected option 1 and option 2 if they are both selected. Ive managed to to this for my dropdown using innerHTML but am unsure how to achieve this for the checkboxes. any ideas on how i can do this? thanks for any advice.

Comment: Post your `calculate()` function?

Comment: What do you mean by "display the text before each checkbox back to the user"?

Comment: Same question... what do you mean by "display" the text before each checkbox?

Comment: just want to show which options have been selected in a div to the side of the boxes, by displaying the 'option 1', 'option 2' and 'option 3' text according to which are selected. Im almost there now using Gokhans method. Only displays one of the selected options atm though, im trying to implement it into what ive already done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML

```
<form id="extras">
    <label id="lbl_1">option 1</label><input type="checkbox" name="box" value="2000" id="1" onchange="calculate()"><br>
        <label id="lbl_2">option 2</label><input id="2" type="checkbox" name="box" value="500" onchange="calculate()"><br>
        <label id="lbl_3">option 3</label><input type="checkbox" name="box" value="150" id="3" onchange="calculate()"><br><br>
</form>
        <span id="txt"></span>
```

Calculate function

```
function calculate()
    {
        document.getElementById("txt").innerHTML = "";
      var checkBoxes = document.getElementsByName("box");
      for(var i=0; i < checkBoxes.length;i++)
      { 
          if(checkBoxes[i].checked)
          {           
document.getElementById("txt").innerHTML += document.getElementById("lbl_" checkBoxes[i].id).innerHTML
          }
      }

    }
```

And [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bR3wU/)

Comment: i have this working now, thanks a lot. only thing is it displays both on the same line and i would like to add a line break to separate them. not too sure how to do this. help would be appreciated.

Comment: change the relevant line to document.getElementById("lbl_" checkBoxes[i].id).innerHTML + "<br>";

Comment: perfect, think that was the one place i didnt try putting the <br>. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. I wrote this in jQuery, but you can convert it to vanilla JS.

```
http://jsfiddle.net/P2BfF/
```

Essentially you need to create labels for your checkboxes:

```
<label for='snow'>option 1</label>
```

Then based on checked, you can display the innerHTML of that element.

Here is my JS:

```
    var checkboxes = $('#extras').find('input[type=checkbox]');

checkboxes.on('click',function() {
    var selected = [];
    checkboxes.each(function(idx,item) {

        if (item.checked)
           selected.push( $('label[for="' + item.id + '"]').html() );
    });

    return alert(selected);
});
```

Comment: i havent used jquery yet so not too sure about this. thanks though, might try to translate it =]